# SharePoint Logic Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, app

Can any one explain me that what is SharePoint logic apps and how can we use it?. I googled this but all I found is azure logic apps , which have many connector like yammer connector, SharePoint connector. etc

But I am not getting any solution regarding logic app and how we can use it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing like **Logic Apps in SharePoint**, additionally there is no official release notes on SharePoint Logic Apps.

We have **Flow Apps in SharePoint** which is same as Logic Apps in Azure. I used Flow app in SharePoint Online to create Workflow like functionality which synchronized with ***Mail Chimp***.

For more details on Flow apps you can go through [Flow in SharePoint](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) and [SharePoint and Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sharepoint-and-flow/)

Moreover you can also use Logic Apps to connect to SharePoint. If you need information about how to connect Logic Apps with SharePoint you can find this [post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2015/03/26/creating-an-azure-logic-app-that-connects-with-sharepoint-online.aspx) interesting

Let me know if you need more assist.